# How do I use spread operator in useEffect without infinite loop?

Tags: reactjs

I code a Chrome extension.
popup.html is implemented in React as follows:

```
const [blogUrls, setblogUrls] = useState<string[]>([]);

useEffect(() => {
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    const newBlogUrls = [...blogUrls, ...request.param.blogUrls];
    setblogUrls(newBlogUrls);

    return true;
  });
}, [blogUrls]);
```

How do I avoid an infinite loop?

I know it's not good to write `[blogUrls]` even though I wrote `setblogUrls(newBlogUrls)`.

But I want to write like `[...blogUrls,`.

Please tell me how to resolve this contradiction.

Comment: you have added blogUrls as an dependency in useEffect and also updating it in callback  of useEffect. That is triggering an infinite loop. Remove dependency of useEffect.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
useEffect(() => {
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    const newBlogUrls = [...blogUrls, ...request.param.blogUrls];
    setblogUrls(newBlogUrls);

    return true;
  });

  return () => chrome.runtime.onMessage.removeEventListener();
}, []);
```

it will execute once after page render. your dependency blogUrls is changing after rendering page inside the useEffect itself. so useEffect calling itself again and again. So, its creating infinite loop. To render one time, just make sure it should be empty dependency in useEffect.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
useEffect(() => {
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    setblogUrls((v) => [...v, ...request.param.blogUrls]);

    return true;
  });

  // Don't forget to clean the listener
  return () => chrome.runtime.onMessage.removeEventListener()
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your code adds a listener on every render.

```
// runs on every render
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
```

2. Remove the listener as -

```
const [blogUrls, setblogUrls] = useState<string[]>([]);

function onBlogUrlsChanged(request) {
    const newBlogUrls = [...blogUrls, ...request.param.blogUrls];
    setblogUrls(newBlogUrls);
}

useEffect(() => {
    chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(onBlogUrlsChanged);
    return () => {
      chrome.runtime.onConnect.removeListener(onBlogUrlsChanged);
    }
  }, []);
```

It's ok to run the `useEffect` only once by passing `[]` parameter., We don't wastefully attach and detach the listener every time the component is re-rendered.